# Local (LAN) multiplayer with one Steam account

Tags: steam

My son and I would like to play a Steam game in multiplayer. How do I set this up? Do I need two Steam accounts, or is this possible with one (Family) account?

Comment: This link describes a slightly advanced process that might be helpful to some readers, to quickly switch between Steam accounts on Windows, using one Steam account per local Windows user, and using a customized shortcut to run Steam as a different local user without having to switch Windows users or log in/out of Steam every time. https://achievementhunting.com/guides/multiple_steam_accounts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **You do need two Steam accounts**: a shared Steam library (through Family Library Sharing) can't be used simultaneously by two (or more) people. As per [Steam's FAQ](https://store.steampowered.com/promotion/familysharing):

  > Can two users share a library and both play at the same time? 
  >   
  > No, a
  >   shared library may only be accessed by one user at a time.
- Setting up a local multiplayer game is **dependent on the game**, and usually this can be done relatively easily in-game.